# CollapsingToolbarLayout doesn't show the RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to implement Coordinator Layout with collapsing toolbar layout and has recycler view into the nestedScrollView when run the app the toolbar collapse is working but the recycler view doesn't show up

**and here's my xml code :**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:background="#444"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello Wolrd" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rec"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="#00FFCC"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="100dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/pic"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In my opinion you do not need a `NestedScrollView` at all.
2. Try to set `LinearLayout`'s height (parent of yours `RecyclerView`) to `match_parent` insteadof `wrap_content`